# latex command for diagonal matrix of this kind

Tags: math-mode

[image: diagonal matrix]

Could anyone give me code for this matrix generation?

Comment: Do you want a generic command which autogenerates this, or do you just want to know how to produce it? `\begin{bmatrix}d_{1} & & \\ & \ddots & \\ & & d_{r}\end{bmatrix}` would do

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do this very simply with a `bmatrix` and `\ddots` for the diagonal dots. The `b` in `bmatrix` is for the (square) brackets. `pmatrix` would give you parentheses, `Bmatrix` would give you braces and `vmatrix` and `Vmatrix` give you single and double vertical lines (respectively).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  D =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    d_{1} & & \\
    & \ddots & \\
    & & d_{r}
  \end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I will add here as well that, although not everyone loves its use, the physics package allows you to generate such an output by writing:
    
    D=\mqty[\dmat[0]{d_1,\ddots,d_r}]